# Blocked a frame with origin chrome-extension from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to pass a message from a content script through background.js to a window I have popped up in background.js in a chrome extension, but making a reference to the window I have popped up within the background.js, in the event handler in background.js, causes a cross origin permission problem.

Here is the offending background.js code:

```
// background.js
var win;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  win = window.open('popup.html', '', 'width=1530px,height=950px');
  
  // listen to messages from inject.js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(win); // Any reference to "win" causes the error
  });
  
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'jquery-latest.min.js'});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'inject.js'});
});
```

I am getting this error from background.js:

**Error in event handler: Error: Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://apjalhbpkiomjnmiilehodbmfcebfiib" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at console.log ()
at chrome-extension://apjalhbpkiomjnmiilehodbmfcebfiib/background.js:10:13**

It appears merely referencing the variable win has caused a cross origin problem, which I don't understand, because I declared win in background.js and referenced it in background.js, albeit in an event handler.

Here is a minimal extension that duplicates the problem (the error will appear in the console of the background page): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8ge0v398xzq04th/AACqjNH4h9QS_LaPwCZYK-iwa?dl=0

Comment: is `popup.html` part of the extension

Comment: Yes it is in the same unpacked directory. The window is opened and successfully rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening because the popup window is sandboxed in the manifest. It doesn't happen if the window isn't sandboxed. Maybe it's a bug as reported at https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-apps/c/YGLdHCAfOiU?pli=1
You are meant to be able to use postMessage to send to a sandboxed window.
I wanted to sandbox the popup because I want to use plotly there, which uses function constructors, which is considered unsafe-eval.